# Vue / Vuex State Management best practice for auth

Tags: vue.js, state, vue-router, vuex

Not sure if this is the right place for this question since its more of "best practice" and not technical per say but I am new to building a SPA with Vue. From what I have seen so far Vuex is a good tool to handle the state of cross component application data. What I currently have is working good for my user, logged in status and side-drawer menu state (open / closed), but before I go down a rabbit hole I wanted to get some community input on my `store.js` setup. Auth uses JWT.

Is it good practice to use store to handle login, logout and the user info? All the tutorials I have found are not to real world (using it for a counter or something).

If this is not the appropriate place to ask this before down voting, please let me know the right Stack Exchange site to ask.

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';


export const store = new Vuex.Store({

    state:{
        isLoggedIn: !!localStorage.getItem("jwt_token"),
        user: localStorage.getItem("user")? JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("user") ) : {},
        showDrawer: false
    },

    mutations:{

        login: state =>{

            state.isLoggedIn = true;

            state.user = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("user") );

            //set the Axios header so we pass Auth on the API
            window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = localStorage.getItem("jwt_token");

        }, 

        logout: state =>{

            localStorage.setItem("jwt_token", '');

            localStorage.setItem("user", '');

            state.isLoggedIn = false;

            state.user = {};

            state.showDrawer = false;
        },

        openDrawer: state =>{
            state.showDrawer = true;
        },

        closeDrawer: state =>{
            state.showDrawer = false;
        }
    },

})
```

Comment: Yes i don't see why not. As your application grows i would put all user/auth data into its own module.

Comment: Check out: https://auth0.com/blog/build-an-app-with-vuejs/

Answer (score 2):

Hi I am using this pattern.

https://blog.sqreen.io/authentication-best-practices-vue/

It achieves:

- Isolated authentication logic from the app and other libs.
- No need to explicitly pass tokens to every API call.
- Handle all unauthenticated API calls
- Has auto authentication
- Has restricted routes access
- Separation of concerns
- Avoid side effects
- Action dispatch can return promises

  Hope it helps